# How does EmberJS deal with different output between findRecord() & findAll()?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have a simple model `my-data`:

```
export default Model.extend({
  foo: attr(),
  bar: attr()
});
```

Let's also say my backend is setup so when I use `findAll()` which calls `/api/v1/my-data/`, the response only returns the `foo` attribute, but if I use `findRecord()` -- eg, `/api/v1/my-data/5` --, the response contains both `foo` and `bar`.

Is EmberJS smart enough to merge these two responses without overwriting any attribute that's not in the response? In other words, if I first do a `findRecord('my-data', 5)`, then both `foo` & `bar` will be set, but if I subsequently call `findAll()`, which will also contain record `5`, can I expect the record with id `5` to still have both `foo` and `bar` set, or will `findAll()` completely overwrite record `5` with `bar` becoming unset or NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is EmberJS smart enough to merge these two responses without
>   overwriting any attribute that's not in the response?

Yes. [sample twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ff3212f65d20865ebc382733c0167fcd?numColumns=2&openFiles=routes.application.js%2Ccontrollers.application.js)